# How would I create a filename filter in PHP similar to Subversion's global-ignores?

Tags: php

I would like to build something to filter filenames in a fashion similar to SVN's `global-ignores format`. I am guessing it might be best to parse the string (below) and generate a regular expression for it, but I am not sure if there is a better way to do this or if it has already been implemented somewhere.

```
*.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store
```

Alternate suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`fnmatch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) (`glob()` does not support negation).

Comment: This technically answers my question, but I think I may go with a `preg_match` solution anyway. I have a feeling that it will be more efficient than looping around a bunch of `fnmatch()` calls for each pattern.